# Sails.js : Waterline OR filter not working

Tags: node.js, sails.js, where-clause, waterline

I am developing a [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/#!/) app using default [waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline).

I have an array of categories and locations as shown below.

```
var categoryOrFilter = [1,2,3];
var locationsOrFilter = [8,9,10];
```

I am trying to write a `where` on my `model` which will filter the model items belonging to at least one of the `categories` in the `categoryOrFilter` **AND** at least one of the `locations` in the `locationsOrFilter`.

My model is as shown below.

```
attributes: {

        category: {
            model: 'category'
        },

        location: {
            model: 'location'
        }

}
```

I've written my query as shown below.

```
 Model.find()
        .where({
            or: [{
                "category": categoryOrFilter
            }]
        })
        .where({
            or: [{
                "location": locationsOrFilter
            }]
        })
        .exec(function (err, modelItem) {
             //Some logic
        });
```

My categoryOrFilter values are not being considers. My locationOrFilter values work perfect.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd where and the 'or' are not needed the default operator between criteria parts is AND and for array elements in a single criteria part it's IN

```
Model.find()
    .where({
            "category": categoryOrFilter,
            "location": locationsOrFilter
    })
    .exec(function (err, modelItem) {
         // Some logic
    });
```

Comment: Perfect! That was a life savior.